# Given a graph with a distinct path connected by edges, prove

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given a graph such that there is a distinct path $u_{0}-u_{1}-...-u_{n}$ connected by edges such that $d(v_0,v_n) = n \ge 3$. Prove that $ d(v_{0},v_{i}) = i$ for all $0 \le i \le n-3$.

I am having a hard time doing this, because I am not exactly sure what I am trying to prove. Doesn't the fact that there exists a distinct path $u_{0}-u_{1}-...-u_{n}$ already imply  $d(v_{0},v_{i}) = i$ for all $0 \le i \le n-3$? I would love if someone could walk me through the proof.

Comment: I take it that $d(x,y)$ is the length of the shortest path between $x$ and $y$.  So all you are given in that $d(v_0,v_i)\leq i$.  You have to show that there is no shorter path.  (It's a one-liner.)

Comment: Assume for contradiction that there is a shorter path, which implies there is a $(_{0},_{})$ which equals $a$, for some $a <(v_{0},v_{}) $ , but that is a contradiction since (,)  is the shortest possible path? This question is worth quite a bit of points and I feel like I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that in a path $u_{0} - u_{2} - \cdots - u_{n}$ we have $d(u_{0}, u_{i}) = i$ for any $0 \leq i \leq n - 3$.

Now, from the question we have a unique path $P$ such that $d(u_{0}, u_{i}) = i \leq n - 3$. Suppose by contradiction that there exists another path $Q$ such that $d(u_{0}, u_{j}) = j \leq n - 3$ and $d(u_{0}, u_{j}) = j \leq i = d(u_{0}, u_{i})$.

*Note that $u_{i} = u_{j}$. That is; vertex $u_{i}$ and vertex $u_{j}$ are the same under consideration, the subscripts just denote the distance between the vertex and initial vertex $u_{0}$.*

Applying the triangle inequality, it yields the following:

$d(u_{0}, u_{i}) \leq d(u_{0}, u_{j}) + d(u_{j}, u_{i}) =  d(u_{0}, u_{j}) + 0 = j$, since $d(u_{i}, u_{j}) = 0$. Hence, we have a contradiction and that there's no shorter path. $\blacksquare$